# Rails relational table with multiple id's from the same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I know that if I name a column in a table "othertablename_id" rails will know to use that column for a belongs_to or other relation. If I want to have multiple id's from the same table, obviously this won't work, because I would have duplicate column names. What is the best way to build a table that relates two rows from the same table? As in an Appointment table that relates exactly two Users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah I've got it

```
belongs_to :user_1, :class_name => "User"
belongs_to :user_2, :class_name => "User"
```

will use columns user_1_id and user_2_id respectively. The columns should be named something more descriptive of course, but it is quite simple.

Comment: What if you have to set up a query with "n" number of joins to the same table? I'd like to do this same action, but with "n" number of joins, so I'd like something a bit more elegant.

Comment: Nice, dude - it's 2016, and this is still helping me.

Answer (score 0):

A model like:

```
Appointment 
=================
source_user_id
object_user_id
```

would help?

**EDIT** Reading the [rails bible](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails-third-edition) at page 361, I extracted this:

> **Many-to-Many Relationships**
>
> ...A product can belong to many
>   categories, and each category may
>   contain multiple products. This is an
>   example of a many-to-many
>   relationship. It’s as if each side of
>   the relationship contains a collection
>   of items on the other side.

[alt text http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/4004/dibujolfa.png](http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/4004/dibujolfa.png)

> In Rails we express this by adding the
>   has_and_belongs_to_many declaration to
>   both models. From here on in, we’ll
>   abbreviate this declaration to
>   “habtm.” Many-to-many associations are
>   symmetrical—both of the joined tables
>   declare their association with each
>   other using “habtm.”
>
> Within the database, many-to-many
>   associations are implemented using an
>   intermediate join table. This contains
>   foreign key pairs linking the two
>   target tables. Active Record assumes
>   that this join table’s name is the
>   concatenation of the two target table
>   names in alphabetical order. In our
>   example, we joined the table
>   categories to the table products, so
>   Active Record will look for a join
>   table named categories_products.

So, I think that all you have to do, is to use the **has_and_belongs_to_many** declaration.

Comment: then how do i tell rails to use those columns in the relations. (belongs_to :user, PROBABLY SOMETHING HERE RIGHT?)

Comment: thanks, and what you're saying is true, but it does not solve the problem I had in mind. I need to have the two rows that are referred to be distinguished as separate properties. Again, thanks though.